# Configurar Cronjob para executar de 5 em 5 minutos, quando estiver dentre 5 a 20 horas

Tags: linux, cron

Preciso fazer uma configuração para que meu `cronjob` funcione de 5 em 5 minutos. Porém, se a hora do dia for antes de `5`e maior que `20` não quero que rode.

Ou seja, quero um fazer um `cron` que rode de 5 em 5 minutos, porém apenas no intervalo de 5 a 20 horas.

Como posso fazer isso?

Atualmente, tenho um cron que assim:

```
 0,30 * * * * php ~/pasta/para/app/artisan queue:work
```

Qual é a alteração que devo fazer para ele funcionar do jeito que quero?

Comment: Pelo que to vendo parece ser uma aplicação do Laravel, Não seria mais fácil usar um schedule e chamar o command ?

Comment: O Laravel foi só um exemplo. As tags e o conteúdo da pergunta foram no objetivo de entender sobre cronjob mesmo

Answer (score 41, accepted):

O `*/5` significa "a qualquer minuto, mas de 5 em 5".

Dependendo da implementação, basta isso

```
 */5 5-20 * * * php ~/pasta/para/app/artisan queue:work
```

### Sintaxe da *crontab*:

```
*   *   *   *   *       caminho/comando
│   │   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   └────── em quais dias da semana de 0 a 7 (tanto 0 quanto 7 são Domingo)
│   │   │   └────────── em quais meses    (1 - 12)
│   │   └────────────── em quais dias     (1 - 31)
│   └────────────────── em quais horas    (0 - 23)
└────────────────────── em quais minutos  (0 - 59)
```

Especificando cada ítem:

```
*        Todos
1,2,4    Um, dois e Quatro apenas
7-10     De 7 a 10, incluindo 8 e 9
*/5      A qualquer momento, mas com espaço de 5 (ex: 2,7,12,17...)
1-10/3   No intervalo de 1 a 10, mas de 3 em 3 (ex: 2,5,8)
```

**Nota:** quando você usa `/n`, depende do momento em que o `cron` é atualizado pela tabela que o intervalo é contado, portanto, `*/5` pode ser tanto 0,5,10,15 quanto 1,6,11,16.

Um exemplo se precisasse ser a cada 3 horas nesse intervalo:

```
 */5 5-20/3 * * * php ~/pasta/para/app/artisan queue:work
```

Observação: o `cron` não tem intervalos em algumas implementações (não sei se isso procede em alguma distro moderna ainda), pode ser preciso especificar todas as horas:

```
*/5 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 * * * php ~/pasta/para/app/artisan queue:work
```

Mais detalhes no manual da `crontab`:

> http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab