# Configuração do CRON

Tags: cron

Estou tentando rodar um arquivo no cron, mas não estou conseguindo. Teria alguma configuração a mais que precise ser feito?

```
[root@ip-172-31-35-95 ec2-user]# crontab -l
1 * * * * php home/cronrelatorio.php 1
1 * * * * echo "Não entre em pânico" > home/test.txt
```

Joguei o meu script e um echo para testar, mas ele não roda, se eu jogo esses comandos no terminal na "mão" eles rodam sem problema algum.

Obs: Depois de colocar os comandos já restartei o cron e tentei fazer o cron pelo usuario do apache também.

Comment: Quanto tempo você esperou pra ver se estava funcionando? Esse seu cron só vai rodar uma vez por hora.

Comment: Mais detalhes sobre os campos do cron, aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124518/70

Comment: Não seria 1min? o primeiro * dos comandos do cron não são os minutos?

Comment: No link que você mandou está ali, apontando para o primeiro * como minuto de 0-59

Comment: [minutos] [horas] [dias do mês] [mês] [dias da semana] [usuário] [comando]

Comment: Caso eu queira colocar a cada 5minutos eu teria que fazer */5?

Comment: É uma das maneiras. De qualquer forma, editei aquela postagem para melhorar a grafia (em vez de minutos, grafei "em quais minutos" para evitar confusão)

Comment: Começou a funcionar, obrigado está rodando a cada minuto

Comment: Assegure-se de ter uma linha em branco ao final da configuração, e ponha o caminho completo para o binário do PHP para ter certeza que o problema não é esse. Se fizer um teste com um echo, tenha a certeza de estar mandando a saída para um arquivo com permissão.

Comment: Está desta maneira `* * * * * php arquivo.php` para eu rodar a cada 5m seria colocar `*/5 * * * * php arquivo.php` ?

Comment: Faça /caminho/para/o/php /caminho/para/o/arquivo.php para ter certeza que o problema nao é o path. E atenção ao enter no fim da linha. */5 é a cada 5 (no caso, se for no 1o campo, minutos)

Comment: Sim, eles está rodando devidamente agora, só que a cada 1m, para rodar a cada 5 é como eu fiz ali?

Comment: Para cada um normalmente não precisa de */1, bastaria * - agora, cá entre nós, se vc precisa rodar a cada minuto, pode ser o caso de precisar repensar na arquitetura da tarefa. Em situações do cotidiano não é normal isso.

Comment: Não é a cada 1m, é a cada 5m, eu coloquei */5 agora para fazer o teste e funcinou, eu faço a atualização tanto manual quanto pelo cron, é um relatório que preciso de dados reais, mas eu tenho um calculo no meu arquivo que verifica se já passou 5m a partir da ultima hr de atualização, tanto pelo cron quanto manual, se deu os 5m ele roda o arquivo, se não ele da um exit e tenta depois de 5m denovo.

Comment: Ai já começa a ficar mais interessante. Lembre-se que dependendo do caso nem precisa de cron, pode deixar um PHP rodando em loop infinito (via linha de comando), mas com um sleep no meio para dormir por alguns minutos sem ocupar CPU - ai você só usaria o CRON para testar se nao "caiu" o script, com mais intervalo. Mas ai é caso a caso. Qualquer duvida avise.

Comment: Serio? Eu não sabia que existia algo assim, vou pesquisar, obrigado pela ajuda! Não gostaria de dar uma resposta ali embaixo para eu marcar como correta?

Comment: Eu creio que ficaria muito similar à outra, seria melhor depois alguém votar como duplicata se aquela resolveu. Duplicata nao é penalidade, é uma maneira da sua pergunta ficar sempre no site, e servir de link para a outra, ajudando nas buscas dos outros usuários.

Comment: Vou deixar aqui então para que façam isso, obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda.