# Setar timeout para função específica

Tags: php

Tenho um **script com várias funções**.

**Gostaria de setar um *timeout*** (tipo `set_time_limit`) **específico para uma função**, e se estourar o tempo, ele "desconsiderar" e continuar a execução do loop/script.

Exemplo:

```
function teste(){
    sleep(10);
}

foreach($array as $v) {
    echo $v;
    teste();
}
```

*Considerando o exemplo, a função `teste()` irá executar por 10 segundos a cada loop.*

Então **quero setar um *timeout* de 3 segundos para a função**, e caso "estourar" o tempo, ele descarta, e **continua o *loop***.

- Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: A biblioteca ReactPHP provê formas de se implementar está funcionalidade. Com funções especifícas do PHP, acredito que você não conseguirá este comportamento. [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minha curiosidade me levou a esta resposta. Não sei se é a melhor solução, mas funciona. Para fazer o que você quer eu consegui usando `exec`do php para executar o arquivo que contém a função `teste()` em plano de fundo. Assim:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,2,1];

foreach($array as $v) {
    $var = exec('C:\xampp\php\php.exe  '. __DIR__ .'\teste.php '.$v, $saida);
    echo $var;
}
```

Arquivo **teste.php**

```
error_reporting (0);
set_time_limit(3); 
function teste($sec){
    sleep($sec);
    echo "executou > $sec - ";
}
$sec = $argv[1];
teste($sec);
```

A variável `$v` é lançada como um argumento para o script que é recuperado em `$sec`.

**Resultado**

```
executou > 1 -executou > 2 -executou > 3 -executou > 2 -executou > 1 -
```

Comment: Apesar de eu achar válida idéia (apesar de não responder diretamente à duvida da pergunta), o que você fez ai é trocar o crontab ou um agendador de tarefas por um PHP (não tou dizendo que isso é ruim, só acho interessante observar.). Se for bem implementada sua idéia, dá pra fazer um "crontab configurado pelo DB", por exemplo (até cheguei a sugerir isso numa resposta antiga minha).

Comment: @Bacco verdade! Um crontab seria uma opção interessante.

Comment: Quis dizer o oposto, você aproveitar sua idéia e fazer um "crontab próprio" para usar com PHP (mas não pro caso da pergunta). Pq o crontab original você tem que mexer pelo shell, um PHP assim pode servir como agendador para um sistema em PHP configuravel por painel, pq sendo executado pelo shell ele pode ter loop infinito (desde que tenha um sleep pra liberar cpu pras outras coisas, claro).

Comment: @Bacco entendi. Eu nunca usei o cron, apenas ouvi falar. Me parece que ele não é dinâmico né? Você configura uma certa data e horário ele executa um script certo?

Comment: É um serviço que a cada minuto pode executar uma tarefa, e você configura assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124518/70

Comment: Em cada linha você põe uma definição de tempo, um executável e seus argumentos. A cada minuto o crontab vai verificar a lista de horários e executar o que for apropriado praquele momento.

Comment: Por exemplo, a tarefa da linha um todo sábado, a cada meia hora. a da linha dois toda segunda, quarta e sexta às 12h e 19h30... A da linha 3, executa todo dia a cada 7 minutos, e assim vai.

Comment: @Bacco legal. É uma boa solução para executar scripts para atualização de banco backup...